# Can a dead rat deserter make psion attacks through shaped consciousness while transformed?

Tags: dnd-4e

This question looks to explore the relative priority of wording.

[Dead Rat Deserter](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/Theme.aspx?id=868) is a character theme which allows a character to transform into a tiny rat. This rat cannot make attacks as per the power:

> While in rat form, you cannot attack. You retain your game statistics, but gain a climb speed equal to half your normal speed, and a +4 bonus to Stealth checks. Your equipment becomes part of your rat form, and you drop any other items you are holding. You continue to gain the benefits of the equipment you wear, except shields and item powers. While equipment is part of your rat form, it cannot be removed, and anything in a container that is part of your rat form is inaccessible.

[Shaped consciousness](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13300), however:

> You can see, hear, and use psion powers as if you were in your fragment’s space.

Does the positive "you can use powers" from the fragment override the negative "you cannot make attacks in rat form?"

Does it make a difference from which form you invoke the fragment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**

The psion still cannot attack.  To me, the important clause is at the end of the Shaped Consciousness description.

> as if you were in your fragment's space

Essentially then, you have a rat formed psion in it's fragment's space.  It still has the restriction from the Dead rat theme, "you cannot attack".

It doesn't make a difference in which order you do the operations in this case.

Comment: I was about to type up pretty much this :(

Comment: @waxeagle - allow me to save you the trouble!

Comment: To expand, that means the $varForm hengeyoki also would be prohibited?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton - "While in animal form, you cannot use any attack powers, although you can sustain such powers.", so yes, this would also apply to animal form hengeyoki.